# How to make cmd correctly display arabic script?

Tags: python, windows, character-encoding, cmd, arabic

I am running windows 7 and using a python script that outputs some strings in arabic to windows cmd. This is what I get:

[image]

How do I configure cmd show arabic strings correctly?

Comment: you must select an encoding and font for your console that supports the character set you want ... (maybe just the font is sufficient)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your `cmd`'s code page to the encoding you're outputting:

```
chcp 1256
```

That `1256` is an [Arabic code page for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195058.aspx) If you're outputting in another encoding, just find them in the [whole list of code pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and change `1256` to the identifier you want in the command.

Hint: UTF-8 is 65001

Note: To show other characters than `ascii`, Window's `cmd`'s current font must be changed to `Lucida Console` in properties. It's weird I know... Windows :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: hmm, but how do I actually change it from within the script? Cause I double click script.py and new cmd instance is created without chcp 1256, call('chcp 1256') does not work :(

Comment: I see, don't double click it. Go to Run > cmd and open a console. Then issue the `chcp` command. You can't change the console's output encoding from within the script.

Comment: @JoranBeasley of course. That's what I meant :) Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Well, I figured out that I can actually use cygwin. Running the script from cygwin with "Courier New" font does the job.

Comment: @tasty: That's great! I'm glad you made it.

Comment: But **Lucida Console** font doesn't support Arabic characters as listed in [Microsoft Lucida Console font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/lucida-console). You should use **DejaVu Sans Mono** or **Segoe UI** font instead.