# how to display arabic text in cmd?

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I am working in a webaap for Arabian client.In jboss console i am not getting the Arabic texts.In place for Arabic text the console is printing only "????..". Here i am posting the snapshot of my jboss console.[image]

I have tried with this also,as there is a similar question.
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770362/how-to-make-cmd-correctly-display-arabic-script)
I have changed to UTF-8 and it also didn't work for me.
Then i have chcp 1256(for Arabic). Now i can able to write in arabic on cmd.But still i am not getting the system.out.println() Strings in console as it is generating dynamically.I am using a xp machine.

Comment: To know the actual reason, you need to read the following  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

Need to change default font settings as below,

```
1. Notepad         :  By changing font to "Lucida Console"
2. Notepad++    :  By changing Encoding to "UTF-8"
3. Console           :  By changing font and codepage.
```

similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780378/how-to-display-japanese-kanji-inside-a-cmd-window-under-windows) and [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/)

Comment: Thanks ankur,I have tried with colsole2.But it also didn't work me.BTW i have a xp machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default UTF-8 encoding for all cmd windows you need to add this code to the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe]
"CodePage"=dword:0000fde9
```

Or set the encoding for the document in the .bat :
chcp 65001

Next, you need to set the font to display Arabic.

```
CMD Console > right click on the window title > properties > font: SimSun-ExtB
```